# WinRT, ISupportIncrementalLoading, groups and adaptive behavior

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime

I need some help with WinRT (UWP), ISupportIncrementalLoading, ListView and adaptive controls!

I have a ViewModel with an property "Items" which is a IncrementalLoadingCollection (a class which inherits from ObservableCollection and implements ISupportIncrementalLoading). This collection increments its items by calling a webservice. The number of items in the collection is high, so I want my ListView to have a virtualizing panel.

The webservice returns a Foo object with 2 properties:

```
string GroupName { get; }
string Content { get; }
```

I want an adaptive ListView with this behavior:

In phone mode (if global width is below 600), I want every item to have a width stretched, with a specific ItemTemplate for phone (Template1):
[Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QRbK.png)

In tablet/pc mode (if global width is higher than 600), I want every header to have a width stretched and multiple items by row with a specific ItemTemplate for tablet (Template2). The width of each item and the number of items by row depends on the global width. If the global width is between 600 and 800, I want 2 stretched items by row. If the global width is higher than 800, I want 3 stretched items by row:
[Tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oTX2.png)

To resolve the adaptive problem, the main ListView has ItemsWrapGrid as ItemsPanel. I bind the width of each items on a static computed property called AdaptiveItemWidth. This property is computed depending on the width of the app. If the app is in phone mode, AdaptiveItemWidth equals the device width. In tablet mode, it's more complicated, but it's either the half, a third or a quarter of the device width.
Here is the binding:

```
Width="{Binding AdaptiveItemWidth, Source={StaticResource LayoutAdapter}}"
```

I tried some solutions, but none are good.

### 1st solution

I have another property called GroupedItems, refreshed each times the Items add items to itself. GroupedItems is defined like this:

```
return this.Items.GroupBy(i => i.GroupName);
```

Then I use a CollectionView with IsGrouped=true.

This solution don't work because a grouped collection disable the virtualization of the ItemsWrapGrid.

### 2nd solution

The property Items of my ViewModel, is a IncrementalLoadingCollection. GroupedFoo has 2 properties:
string GroupName { get; }
ObservableCollection Items { get; }

At each call of LoadMoreItemsAsync, I create GroupedFoo. If a GroupName already exists in the collection, I add all the Items of the generated GroupedFoo in the existing GroupedFoo. Example:
If I have:

Existing items:

```
{ GroupName: group1, Items: { Foo01, Foo02, Foo03 }}
{ GroupName: group2, Items: { Foo04, Foo05, Foo06 }}
```

Generated items:

```
{ GroupName: group2, Items: { Foo07, Foo08, Foo09 }}
{ GroupName: group3, Items: { Foo10, Foo11, Foo12 }}
```

I return only
{ GroupName: group3, Items: { Foo10, Foo11, Foo12 }}
And I add { Foo07, Foo08, Foo09 } to the existing items in GroupedFoo with GroupName "group2". So, I'll have this:

Existing items:

```
{ GroupName: group1, Items: { Foo01, Foo02, Foo03 }}
{ GroupName: group2, Items: { Foo04, Foo05, Foo06, Foo07, Foo08, Foo09 }}
{ GroupName: group3, Items: { Foo10, Foo11, Foo12 }}
```

In the XAML, I have a template for GroupedFoo with a TextBlock for the GroupName property and a List for the Items property.

This solution works, the adaptive works too, but it's incredibily slow!

### 3rd solution

The property Items of my ViewModel, is a IncrementalLoadingCollection. This collection can have two types:
string represents a header, Foo an item

Then I set the ItemTemplateSelector on my ListView with a template for the Header and another for an item depending on these types.

This solution is simpler and faster than the 2nd one but it works only in phone mode and only if I change the ItemsPanel to a VirtualizingStackPanel. In this solution I can't have an adaptive behavior.

I tried with an ItemsWrapGrid, but all the items have the same size as the Header in phone mode. The VariableSizedWrapGrid can't be used as an ItemsPanel with a ListView and works only with fixed item size.

Any ideas?